# Free library to import FDF into PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, fdf

I am trying to save a **PDF** file by saving the data from the **FDF** into a **PDFTemplate**, in my **WPF** application.

So, the situation is like this. I have a **PDFTemplate.pdf** which serves as a template and has placeholders (or fields). Now I generate this **FDF** file pro-grammatically, which in turn contain all the field names required for the **PDFTemplate** to be filled in. Also, this **FDF** contains the file path for the **PDFTemaplte** also, so that on opening, it knows which **PDF** to use.

Now, when try and double click on the **FDF**, it open the **Adober Acrobat Reader** and displays the **PDFTemplate** with the data filled in. But I can't save this file using the File menu, as it says this file will be saved without the data.

I would like to know if it is possible to import the **FDF** data into **PDF** and save it without using a thrid party component.

Also, if it is very difficult to do this, what would be the possible solution in terms of a free library that would be able to do it?

I just realized that **iTextSharp** is not free for commercial applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to achieve this using another library ***PDFSharp***.

It is somewhat similar to how iTextSharp works except for some places where in iTextSharp is better and easier to use. I am posting the code in case someone would want to do something similar:

```
//Create a copy of the original PDF file from source 
//to the destination location
File.Copy(formLocation, outputFileNameAndPath, true);

//Open the newly created PDF file
using (var pdfDoc = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(
                    outputFileNameAndPath, 
                    PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
{
   //Get the fields from the PDF into which the data 
   //is supposed to be inserted
    var pdfFields = pdfDoc.AcroForm.Fields;

    //To allow appearance of the fields
    if (pdfDoc.AcroForm.Elements.ContainsKey("/NeedAppearances") == false)
    {
        pdfDoc.AcroForm.Elements.Add(
            "/NeedAppearances", 
            new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfBoolean(true));
    }
    else
    {
        pdfDoc.AcroForm.Elements["/NeedAppearances"] = 
            new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfBoolean(true);
    }

    //To set the readonly flags for fields to their original values
    bool flag = false;

    //Iterate through the fields from PDF
    for (int i = 0; i < pdfFields.Count(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the current PDF field
            var pdfField = pdfFields[i];

            flag = pdfField.ReadOnly;

            //Check if it is readonly and make it false
            if (pdfField.ReadOnly)
            {
                pdfField.ReadOnly = false;
            }

            pdfField.Value = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfString(
                             fdfDataDictionary.Where(
                             p => p.Key == pdfField.Name)
                             .FirstOrDefault().Value);

            //Set the Readonly flag back to the field
            pdfField.ReadOnly = flag;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ERROR_FILE_WRITE_FAILURE + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //Save the PDF to the output destination
    pdfDoc.Save(outputFileNameAndPath);                
    pdfDoc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Want to know the possibilities, Is this code will work if the fdf file contains annot instead of fields?